# Ansible postgresql_query Yield AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__version__' Error

Tags: ansible

I have a short Ansible playbook, mybook.yml:

```
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  vars:
    stl_postgres_port: 6543

  tasks:  

  - debug: msg="{{ stl_database }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ stl_postgres_port }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ postgres_password }}"

  - debug: msg="{{ get_db_version }}"

  - name: Check the database versions
    postgresql_query:
      db: "{{ stl_database }}"
      port: "{{ stl_postgres_port }}"
      login_host: localhost
      login_password: "{{ postgres_password }}"
      query: "{{ get_db_version  }}"
    register: db_version_return

  - debug: msg="{{ db_version_return }}"
```

I run it like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook mybook.yml -e "host=my-host"
```

I have the host var files defined at /etc/ansible/host_vars/my-host

```
stl_hostname: my-host
stl_gcp_project: stl-webapp
stl_gcp_zone: us-central1-b
postgres_password: 1234abcd
stl_database: appdbmyhost
get_db_version: select * from webapp.code_version order by webapp_version desc limit 1;
```

I was hoping to get the last entry from webapp_version table. But I am getting the output with the error from the postgresql_query module:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 12 March 2022  05:19:44 +0000 (0:00:00.025)       0:00:00.025 ******** 
ok: [my-host]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 12 March 2022  05:19:46 +0000 (0:00:01.919)       0:00:01.945 ******** 
ok: [my-host] => {
    "msg": "appdbmyhost"
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 12 March 2022  05:19:46 +0000 (0:00:00.026)       0:00:01.971 ******** 
ok: [my-host] => {
    "msg": 6543
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 12 March 2022  05:19:46 +0000 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:01.995 ******** 
ok: [my-host] => {
    "msg": "1234abcd"
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 12 March 2022  05:19:46 +0000 (0:00:00.025)       0:00:02.021 ******** 
ok: [my-host] => {
    "msg": "select * from webapp.code_version order by webapp_version desc limit 1;"
}

TASK [Check the database versions] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 12 March 2022  05:19:47 +0000 (0:00:00.026)       0:00:02.047 ******** 
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__version__'
fatal: [my-host]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to wag-tiger closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/philip/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1647062387.0483847-6513-40239082180393/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py\", line 100, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/philip/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1647062387.0483847-6513-40239082180393/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py\", line 92, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/philip/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1647062387.0483847-6513-40239082180393/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py\", line 41, in invoke_module\r\n    run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\r\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\r\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\r\n    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_postgresql_query_payload_rq74h0ai/ansible_postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py\", line 511, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_postgresql_query_payload_rq74h0ai/ansible_postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py\", line 405, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_postgresql_query_payload_rq74h0ai/ansible_postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/module_utils/postgres.py\", line 192, in get_conn_params\r\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__version__'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
my-host                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Full error:

> Shared connection to wag-tiger closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "/home/philip/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1647062387.0483847-6513-40239082180393/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py", line 100, in \r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File "/home/philip/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1647062387.0483847-6513-40239082180393/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py", line 92, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File "/home/philip/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1647062387.0483847-6513-40239082180393/AnsiballZ_postgresql_query.py", line 41, in invoke_module\r\n    run_name='**main**', alter_sys=True)\r\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module\r\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\r\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code\r\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\r\n  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code\r\n    exec(code, run_globals)\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible_postgresql_query_payload_rq74h0ai/ansible_postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py", line 511, in \r\n  File "/tmp/ansible_postgresql_query_payload_rq74h0ai/ansible_postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py", line 405, in main\r\n  File "/tmp/ansible_postgresql_query_payload_rq74h0ai/ansible_postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/module_utils/postgres.py", line 192, in get_conn_params\r\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**version**'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error

What does AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute "__version__" mean? I don't think I missed anything.

What's interesting is that if I switch the host name, some of them work and I can get the query output. All the host_var files are pretty much the same.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The good thing about those modules being open source is that one can [easily see what the offensive line is](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.postgresql/blob/2.1.1/plugins/module_utils/postgres.py#L192), and in this case it's because `psycopg2` is not available to that module. It's for sure a bug that they didn't [otherwise warn you](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.postgresql/blob/2.1.1/plugins/module_utils/postgres.py#L53), but software is filled with bugs

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But if it truly a bug, how come it works with some other servers when I switch the host?

Comment: I'd presume because the other host's `{{ ansible_python_interpreter }}` _does_ have `psycopg2`; for clarity, the bug is in the ansible module not asserting the `None`-ness of that `psycopg2` name before blindly using it. I haven't bothered to track down why, or whatever, but your experience confirms that is for sure their bug. You have influence over running `- pip: {name: psycopg2, state: present}` before you attempt to blindly use the `postgresql_query:` module, so tomato, tomahto